# How to post status for user in 'Facebook At Work' using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I working on a project related to Facebook At Work. (Fb@W). I have admin access token and community id.
The app need to post statuses on behalf of user in Facebook at work. I tried to add impersonate_token to API call but the result return an error as follow:

"message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

The problem is user can not authenticate facebook at work account. Anyone know how to do this?

Thank you for reading

Comment: have you found a solution yet? I am reading the API docs but there is not a single mention of publishing.

Comment: I haven't found the solution yet. :(
The project has been canceled due to technical problem :(